# Vim edit a symlink

Tags: vim, symlink

I want to edit a file with (`:e`) which is a symlink and make vim follow it. I dont want this to be the default behavior or anything.

I know that using resolve and expand I can get full link.

```
:echo resolve(expand("~/.vimrc"))
```

prints the full link.

I want to be able to do something like this

```
:e resolve(expand("~/.vimrc"))
```

Note:
I want it to follow the symlink because of context, like quickly editing other files in that folder and stuff like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can insert any Vimscript expression into the command-line via `<C-r>` and the *expression register* `=`:

```
:e <C-r>=resolve(expand("~/.vimrc"))<CR><CR>
```

Alternatively, for files, there's the rather obscure *backtick expansion of Vimscript*:

```
:e `=resolve(expand("~/.vimrc"))`<CR>
```

Comment: exactly what I need. curiously it does not work in when i type it as a command in the editor. However when i mapped it to something in my vimrc it works

Comment: I've used the mapping syntax; of course, you need to press Ctrl + R instead of `<C-r>` and Enter instead of `<CR>`!